# Chromium console.error internal implementation - what makes hyperlinked path to files in error stack?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, console, chromium

I noticed that error stack visible while using `console.error` has ability to make URIs hyperlinked. Such formatting takes place as well in browser Devtools as in IDE i use (WebStorm with integrated Git Bash terminal).

Example screen (this comes from Jest testing framework, but such hyperlinks are also provided in usual `console.error` calls):

[image]

As Node.js uses Chrome's V8 JS engine under the hood, i have tried to debug `console.error` internal implementation, but i *hit the wall* [at this line of code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v12.18.3/lib/internal/console/constructor.js#L264) - it uses stream to output the error message, which beforehand is just a string without any special formatting (except new lines) and afterwards becomes formatted output in console (including hyperlinks). I don't know what happens below there.

The `Console.prototype.error` method [seems to be created](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v12.18.3/lib/internal/console/constructor.js#L599) by assigning `Console.prototype.warn` method to it, which is confusing. Also, [Devtools console's inspect function](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities#inspect) won't navigate to the implementation of `console` methods while debugging Node.js, even despite the fact that Node's code is more accessible than the browser's one - i mean it's possible to debug Node's internals to some level, which is not a thing in the browser.

**My question:** is it possible to output hyperlinked content (my intention is to hyperlink path to a module) to the console output in a controllable way?

That question arised, because i am writing a Node.js wrapper on `console` methods i use in project and, as i had noticed the hyperlinks to files in call stacks, i wanted to use that feature inside my wrapper. I know there are libraries that wrap `console` and offer a ton of features, but i want to have a tiny wrapper, with just one or two features included. If somebody knows library that offers such controllable hyperlinking to the console output, i'd appreciate sharing a link, so i could look up for it's implementation.

Comment: "*i am writing a Node.js wrapper on console methods*" - what console do you want to display the hyperlinks on ultimately? The browser devtools and an IDE terminal are both very special.

Comment: I primarily want it to be displayed in IDE, but sometimes during Node debugging it would be convenient to have such hyperlinks also available in Chrome Devtools.

Comment: Afaict, this is a feature of the IDE - it just looks through any output to find something that looks like a file path and links it.

Comment: I tried to pass file path to `console.log` and it didn't output it as hyperlink, so i think there is something under the hood of `console.error` implementation that wraps file paths in call stack with hyperlinks.

Answer (score 2):

### IDE

As others have already mentioned in comments: links are a feature of the IDE/Text Editor. You can provide a file path, but it may not be clickable depending on your IDE/Text Editor. E.g., `` console.error(`${__filepath}:${line}:${column}`) ``

### Browser (Chromium Based)

Yes, this is possible to some extent. Just prefix the file path with `file:///`.

```js
// index.js

const line = 2;
const column = 9;

console.error('ERROR: ', `file:///${__filename}:${line}:${column}`.replace(/\\/g, '/'));
console.log('done'); // set a breakpoint here inside of devtools
```

1. Run `node --inspect-brk index.js`
2. Open [chrome://inspect](http://chrome://inspect)
3. Select **Open dedicated DevTools for Node** (this will make sources visible in Devtools > Sources > Node) or **inspect** under the node process.
4. Allow the code to run to your breakpoint. Check the console and click the link

[image]

[image]

#### NOTES

- `replace(/\\/g)` will make sure the path is valid (at least on Windows)
- This is one of the rare places that `file:///` links work in the browser.
- You could also generate sourcemaps and link to the `sourceMappingURL`
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Use_a_source_map